# Xamarin Android app hangs on in splash screen

Tags: xamarin.android, release, android-appcompat, android-8.0-oreo, reactiveui

We are developing a **Xamarin Android** app using **ReactiveUI**. Following are the technical specifications,

- Visual Studio 2017 15.7.4
- **Target framework** - Mono Android 8.0
- NetStandard 2.0
- ReactiveUI 8.2
- Xamarin Android Support 26.1.1
- CompileSdkVersion - API level 26(Android 8.0)
- TargetSdkVersion - API level 26(Android 8.0)
- MinSdkVersion - API level 19(Android 4.4)

My Project Properties Release Configurations are below.

- [application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GzFfh.png)
- [MANIFEST](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IHNUP.png)
- [android options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jxdVd.png)
- [android_options_advanced](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T7ylj.png)

I tested whole development using Huawei API 19(INSTRUCTION SET -  armeabi-v8a.) It went ok with debugging and release configurations. 
I used custom theme from Theme.appCompat as application theme. And I have styles.xml in values and values-v21 folders. Both same name. I have used a **ProcessDialog** in Splashing screen which is determined as deprecated. Where is the issue? I am new to Xamarin Android. Thanks in advance.

Update: 
Followings is how my **MainActivity.cs** Looks like.

```
using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.Content.PM;
using Android.Graphics.Drawables;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Support.Design.Widget;
using Android.Support.V4.View;
using Android.Support.V4.Widget;
using Android.Support.V7.App;
using Android.Util;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using DistributrIII.Mobile.Droid.Activities.Errors;
using DistributrIII.Mobile.Droid.Activities.Login;
using DistributrIII.Mobile.Droid.Activities.PointOfSale;
using DistributrIII.Mobile.Droid.Fragments.CloseOfTheDay;
using DistributrIII.Mobile.Droid.Fragments.Common;
using DistributrIII.Mobile.Droid.Fragments.Lossess;
using DistributrIII.Mobile.Droid.Fragments.Orders;
using DistributrIII.Mobile.Droid.Fragments.Outlets;
using DistributrIII.Mobile.Droid.Fragments.PointOfSale;
using DistributrIII.Mobile.Droid.Fragments.Reports;
using DistributrIII.Mobile.Droid.Fragments.SaleOrder;
using DistributrIII.Mobile.Droid.Fragments.PurchaseOrder;
using DistributrIII.Mobile.Droid.Fragments.Settings;
using DistributrIII.Mobile.Droid.Util;
using DistributrIII.Mobile.Lib.Model.Common;
using DistributrIII.Mobile.Lib.Model.Login;
using DistributrIII.Mobile.Lib.Model.Sync;
using DistributrIII.Mobile.Lib.VM.MainActivity;
using DistributrIII.Mobile.Lib.VM.Util;
using Java.Interop;
using Java.IO;
using ReactiveUI;
using System;
using System.Reactive.Concurrency;
using System.Reactive.Linq;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using static Android.Support.V7.App.ActionBar;
using static Android.Support.V7.Widget.SearchView;
using Environment = Android.OS.Environment;
using SearchView = Android.Support.V7.Widget.SearchView;
using DistributrIII.Mobile.Droid.Fragments.OpenTransactions;

namespace DistributrIII.Mobile.Droid
{
    [Activity(Label = "DistributrIII", MainLauncher = false, Theme = "@style/MainTheme")]
    public class MainActivity : DistributrBaseActivity<MainActivityVM>
    {
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);            
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.activity_main);
            SetupUI(savedInstanceState);
        }

        #region UI Components
        DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
        NavigationView navigationView;
        IMenuItem previousItem;
        Android.Support.V7.Widget.Toolbar toolbar;
        DisplayScreen PreviousMenuItemId = DisplayScreen.None;
        SearchView searchControl;
        ProgressDialog progress;
        #endregion

        #region UI Helper Methods

        public override bool OnCreateOptionsMenu(IMenu menu)
        {
            return base.OnPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
        }


    private void SetupUI(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        toolbar = FindViewById<Android.Support.V7.Widget.Toolbar>(Resource.Id.toolbar);
        toolbar.InflateMenu(Resource.Menu.main_menu);

        searchControl = (SearchView)toolbar.Menu.FindItem(Resource.Id.distributr_search).ActionView ;

        var textChangedObservable =
            Observable
                .FromEventPattern<QueryTextChangeEventArgs>(
                    x => searchControl.QueryTextChange += x,
                    x => searchControl.QueryTextChange -= x)
                .Select(x => x.EventArgs.NewText)
                .Throttle(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1), TaskPoolScheduler.Default);


        var querySubmitObservable =
            Observable
                .FromEventPattern<QueryTextSubmitEventArgs>(
                    x => searchControl.QueryTextSubmit += x,
                    x => searchControl.QueryTextSubmit -= x)
                .Select(x => x.EventArgs.Query);

        SubscriptionDisposables.Add(
            Observable
                .Merge(textChangedObservable, querySubmitObservable)
                .Subscribe(async searchText =>  this.HandleSearch(searchText))

        );

        SetupNavigation(savedInstanceState);
        BottomNavigationView navigationView = (BottomNavigationView)FindViewById(Resource.Id.bottom_navigation);

        if (DIIIStaticStorage.LoginAccountType == LoginAccountType.Customer)
        {
            navigationView.InflateMenu(Resource.Menu.nav_bottom_customr);
        }
        else
        {
            navigationView.InflateMenu(Resource.Menu.nav_bottom);
        }

        navigationView.NavigationItemSelected += BottomNavigation_NavigationItemSelected;
        Android.Support.Design.Internal.BottomNavigationMenuView menuView = (Android.Support.Design.Internal.BottomNavigationMenuView)navigationView.GetChildAt(0);
        for (int i = 0; i < menuView.ChildCount; i++)
        {
            Android.Support.Design.Internal.BottomNavigationItemView itemView = (Android.Support.Design.Internal.BottomNavigationItemView)menuView.GetChildAt(i);
            itemView.SetShiftingMode(false);
            itemView.SetChecked(false);
        }

        //InvalidateOptionsMenu();
        toolbar.Title = "Distributr";
    }
}
```

*I observed this stuck in debug mode also with some devices.[log](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1xaC6yO9hUZzNxXOnESH0g8aBmNSnf119) can someone show me whats the error.Thanks again*

Comment: Can you show some code?

Comment: I have updated the question with MainActivity.cs Code Snippet

Comment: Hi my friend, may be you should test your app with an older versión of VS, VS 15.7 have some issues with xamarin.